# How do I add an extra description row under the name of algorithm?

Tags: algorithms

The following image is my goal. You can see there is a row to describe the parameters of Algorithm1. I wonder how to add rows like this.

And I also wonder how to add the description of the following function under the Algorithm1 such that they are like a body(there is no blank). I believe they use the same technique.
[image: My goal]

My codes is as follows if you want it. But you can just use simple lines to help me.  I'd be very glad if you can help me. Thanks!!!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}

An algorithm for test.

\begin{center}
    \begin{algorithm}[H]
        \KwIn{$p_1=(a_1, b_1), \ldots, p_{10}=(a_{10}, b_{10})$, ten points$p_i(1 \leq i \leq 10)$ on an Euclidean plane.}  % Algorithm inputs
        \KwOut{$dist$, the distance  the closest pair of points.} %Algorithm outputs
        \medskip
        compute $dist \leftarrow$ MaxValue; \algorithmiccomment{MaxValue is the maximus value of the type of $dist$.}

        \For{$i \leftarrow 1$ {\rm to} $10$ }{
            \For{$j \leftarrow i$ {\rm to} $10$}{
                $tempDist \leftarrow$ GetDistance($p_i, p_j$) \\
                \If{$dist < tempDist$}{
                    $dist \leftarrow tempDist$ 
                }
            }
        }
        \Return{dist}
        \caption{\texttt{TheShortestDistancev1}} % Algorithm name
        \label{alg:TheShortestDistancev1}   % optional label to refer to
    \end{algorithm}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It will be easier to help you if you complete your example of code to make it *compilable*, so it should start with `\documentclass{...}` and end with `\end{document}`. Else, we have to guess a part of what you're doing (for example: what package are you using to create algorithms?)

Comment: @Vincent I updated my questions just now. I'm sorry I ignored that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't mix the use of [`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) and [`algorithmicx`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx)'s `algpseudocode`. Both provide their own functionality. Instead, use the [`algorithms` bundle](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithms)'s `algorithm` package (for floating behaviour/styling) and `algpseudocode` for styling of the code.

Below you'll see something that resembles your output, using `\State`s for each statement within the algorithm and `\fsmid` to set a `mid`dle rule `f`loat `s`tyle (provided by [`float`](//ctan.org/pkg/float) in the form of `\@fs@mid`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% Just for this example

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fsmid}{\par\@fs@mid}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\var}{\texttt}
\newcommand{\func}{\textit}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{TheShortestDistancev1}% Algorithm name
  
  Here are some additional parameters
  \fsmid
  
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Require $p_1 = (a_1, b_1), \dots, p_{10} = (a_{10}, b_{10})$, ten points $p_i$ ($1 \leq i \leq 10$) on an Euclidean plane.% Algorithm inputs
    \Ensure $\var{dist}$, the distance  the closest pair of points.% Algorithm outputs

    \medskip

    \State compute $\var{dist} \leftarrow \var{MaxValue}$ \Comment{\var{MaxValue} is the maximum value of the type of $\var{dist}$.}

    \For{$i \leftarrow 1~\textrm{to}~10$ }
      \For{$j \leftarrow i~\textrm{to}~10$}
        \State $\var{tempDist} \leftarrow \func{GetDistance}(p_i, p_j)$
        \If{$\var{dist} < \var{tempDist}$}
          \State $\var{dist} \leftarrow \var{tempDist}$
        \EndIf
      \EndFor
    \EndFor
    \State \Return $\var{dist}$
  \end{algorithmic}

  \medskip
  
  \fsmid
  \textbf{function} Some other function
  \fsmid
  
  \begin{algorithmic}
    \Require $p_1 = (a_1, b_1), \dots, p_{10} = (a_{10}, b_{10})$, ten points $p_i$ ($1 \leq i \leq 10$) on an Euclidean plane.% Algorithm inputs
    \Ensure $\var{dist}$, the distance  the closest pair of points.% Algorithm outputs

    \medskip

    \State compute $\var{dist} \leftarrow \var{MaxValue}$ \Comment{\var{MaxValue} is the maximum value of the type of $\var{dist}$.}

    \For{$i \leftarrow 1~\textrm{to}~10$ }
      \For{$j \leftarrow i~\textrm{to}~10$}
        \State $\var{tempDist} \leftarrow \func{GetDistance}(p_i, p_j)$
        \If{$\var{dist} < \var{tempDist}$}
          \State $\var{dist} \leftarrow \var{tempDist}$
        \EndIf
      \EndFor
    \EndFor
    \State \Return $\var{dist}$
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have learned a lot from your answer.